# How to get an array from a class in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

i am very newbie, please forgive for my inexperienced knowledges.
I have a class in PHP. It makes some database job.
But i couldn't get results as array.

```
public function __construct($sunucu, $kullaniciAdi, $kullaniciSifre, $veritabaniAdi){
$this->_baglanti= mysql_connect($sunucu, $kullaniciAdi,$kullaniciSifre);
mysql_select_db($veritabaniAdi,$this->_baglanti);
}

public function baglantiyiKopar(){
mysql_close($this->_baglanti);
}

public function sorgula($sorgu){
$this->_donenSonuclar = mysql_query($sorgu, $this->_baglanti);
$this->_satirSayisi = mysql_num_rows($this->_donenSonuclar) ;
}

public function satirSayisi(){
return $this->_satirSayisi;
}

public function satirlar(){
$satirlar = array();
for($st=0;$st< $this->_satirSayisi;$st++){
$satirlar = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->_donenSonuclar);
}
return $satirlar;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Please note that the mysql_* functions are now deprecated ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php ). You should be using MySQLi or PDO instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean this function, you need to change it a little bit:

```
public function satirlar(){
  $satirlar = array();
  for($st=0;$st< $this->_satirSayisi;$st++){
    $satirlar[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->_donenSonuclar);
             ^^ add a new entry to the array instead of overwriting the existing one
  }
  return $satirlar;
}
```

Also note that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and it is recommended to switch to PDO (or mysqli) with prepared statements and bound variables.

Comment: I understand it is better to rewrite this class using MySQLi or PDO. Thank you @juco and Jeroen.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function satirlar(){
  $satirlar = array();
  for($st=0;$st< $this->_satirSayisi;$st++){
    $satirlar[$st] = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->_donenSonuclar);
  }
  return $satirlar;
}
```